# logical indexing based on multiple conditions

Tags: matlab

I am trying to return a logical vector based on multiple search conditions. I thought this was quite simple and sure it probably is.

So I'm just trying a very simple example. I have a vector 10 x 1 of type double, called myVec. Where the element in myVec is equal to 5 or 8 I would like a 1 returned otherwise a 0 returned.

```
myVec
5
3 
8
9
1
8
5
6
7
5
```

My result vector should look something like below,

```
Result
1
0
1
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
```

I have tried the following,

```
rl = find(myVec == 8 | myVec == 5);
rl = myVec == 8 | myVec == 5;
```

Both attempts give the message,

Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.

**Update**

Here is my actual vector that I was playing with,

```
 myVec = [3 5 12 34 62 98 45 12 12 64 20 5 5 94 87 21 20]';
```

Here is the line of code I was trying use that throws the error but appears it should work,

```
 rl = myVec  == 12 | myVec  == 5 | myVec  = 20;
```

Comment: rl = myVec == 8 | myVec == 5; works for me

Comment: Have you pre-assigned something to `rl`? if you type `clearvars rl` followed by your second method do you still get that error?

Comment: just did clearvars rl still getting the same error. I closed Matlab and started again just ran the two lines shown in my update, same error. The example by Stewie Griffin works for me though

Comment: Can you try to recreate the result on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com)? Check out [this link](https://ideone.com/ycorqq) to see that it actually works.

Comment: Ok restarted my computer & it now works. Have no idea why. I ended up using the brackets as shown by Stewie Griffin. Then also did it without brackets and it worked. Computer hadn't be restarted for couple of days. Still bit baffled why it wouldn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
myvec = 1:10;
vec = (myvec == 5 | myvec == 8)
vec =

     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
```

This works without the parentheses too, so there's something else wrong. The `find` version gives the indices of the elements, also without an error. Actually, I find no way to reproduce your error message.

Comment: What's the point of using `(` in this context? This does not provide any operation precedence. Did you mean `(myvec == 5) | (myvec == 8)` maybe?

Comment: True, but IMO it makes it more clear what you're trying to do. Almost like not using parentheses when writing 1/2/3 (on paper). It's strictly speaking not necessary, but it sure as hell helps =P